# Unable to set Binding of a UserControl element in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm working on a WPF application and I don't want to copy/paste code. I want reusable elements like in React/JavaScript. In this particular case I have a DataGrid that I want to use in different locations of my application with different bindings/variables. I don't want to copy/paste the DataGrid-XAML every time

Here is the definition of my template for my DataGrid:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="PersonTableTemplate" >
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="Transparent" RowBackground="Transparent" IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column">
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00000000" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray" />
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00000000" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF151515" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray" />
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Maven Pro" />
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28" />
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="35" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Binding="{Binding Gender}" Width="100" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}" Width="100" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Adress" Binding="{Binding Adress}" Width="100" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

And on some other places I want to use that template as follow:

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding PersonTable}" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonsFromCanada}" Template="{StaticResource PersonTableTemplate}"  />
```

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding PersonTable}" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonsFromMexiko}" Template="{StaticResource PersonTableTemplate}"  />
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work, because the table is always empty.

If I put DataContext and ItemsSource directly into the template, like this...

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PersonTableTemplate" >
    <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding PersonTable}" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonsFromCanada}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="Transparent" RowBackground="Transparent" IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column">
...
```

...then the table is not empty, but (obviously) always has the same content.

How can I pass the different variables PersonsFromCanada and PersonsFromMexiko to the template?

Comment: You should set datacontext in your code behind, now your set for Datacontext doesn't work.

Comment: That's not what Template means in XAML. What you want here, I think, is a UserControl that contains a DataGrid. Also, it's bad practice to set DataContext explicitly in XAML (and *contra* the above, it's even worse practice to set DataContext explicitly in codebehind). Does `PersonTable` have a property (not a field) named `PersonsFromCanada`? Having no idea what your actual viewmodel looks like, I can't tell you what your bindings need to look like.

Comment: What you're doing is replacing the visual content of your DataGrid with a completely different DataGrid. I would suggest not binding DataContext at all. Instead, I would put this on the "outer" datagrid: `ItemsSource="{Binding PersonTable.PersonsFromCanada}"`. On the "inner" DataGrid, inside the Template, I would again NOT bind DataContext. I would use this binding: `ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"`. What that means is, "Go to the parent control that this template was applied to. Find its `ItemsSource` property. Whatever that is, get its value and use that here."

Comment: Most of that could be done just using a style (or 3) rather than template.

Comment: Or you could paste the part between the datagrid tags into a usercontrol. Bind it's itemssource to some property - say genericNamedCollection. Then provide that property in the datacontext where you're using it. I think templating a datagrid like that is a mistake.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for the comments. So when it is a mistake, what is then the right way of reusing the definition of a DataGrid? Style?

Comment: The datagrid is pretty a pretty complex thing. Usually you'd template parts of it rather than the whole thing. Are your columns the same each time?

Comment: @reinoslav It doesn't look like you can set the DataGrid's Columns property via a Style setter, so a UserControl might be your best respectable option. Doing it via `Template` is weird, but, errrr, it does actually work, so... If it ain't broke... Just bear in mind that all the properties on the "outer"/"parent" DataGrid will be ignored unless you do explicit `TemplateBinding`s on the actual DataGrid inside the `ControlTemplate`.

Comment: You'd have to use code to add columns. You could do that using a custom markup extension. Not a fan of that approach though.

Comment: If I use your suggestion, then I get "Cannot find the static member 'ItemsSourceProperty' on the type 'Control'."

Comment: Good point. You need the TargetType attribute on the ControlTemplate so it knows what kind of control you're applying it to: `<ControlTemplate x:Key="PersonTableTemplate" TargetType="DataGrid">`.